# Popping View Controller leaves faded image behind

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

Issue: When I pop my view controller with an image as the background,the view slides to the right like it should; however, it leaves a faded bit at the end for about a second, and THEN it completely pops. In the image below I'm referring to the light rectangle (the dark part of the sliding view was caught in action).

Setup: I'm using storyboards and the issue only happens when the imageView is set to Aspect Fill, which is what I need to use. The image is already blurred, and I've set the NavBar to hidden so I could implement my own back button. Code for the back button is below.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Shifting the imageView to the right in storyboards helps, but there must be something better I can do. See second image below.

[image]

[image]